# Lost requests while deploying new versions of my app

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have two nodejs apps hosted on heroku that communicate through http requests.

My app 1 is sending messages to my app 2. Like a real time messaging app.

However I've noticed that when I deploy new builds of both apps, some requests that are fired at the time of the deployment of the targeted apps fail. Like if they were lost as their target app are updating at this time.

It's very annoying and the consequences are clearly bad for a messaging app as some messages are not delivered due to builds update.

My question is, what do you suggest to avoid this issue in the future ? does heroku have something like a retry system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ideal solution to something like this on a big scale would be a message broker like Apache Kafka or Rabbit MQ. But those are full-fledged systems and can be a bit too heavy to implement in your use case, where we are running across Heroku pods.

A simple workaround is to make the receiver server send a response when it receives a message. The response need not contain any data, but only status codes and empty bodies also work. This will allow you to monitor which requests were landed successfully and which were not able to because the machine was sleeping or updating. Store these into a local queue and keep trying every n second to see if the receiver has started responding. When it doesn't, send the queued messages.

This way you have a method of ensuring that all the messages that are being sent are delivered. With some auxiliary functions, you can get the metrics of downtime, load, etc, but that's completely optional.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's a good idea. I was thinking there was maybe a native retry solution in heroku to handle this situation but It is a good way to manage it too.